# Pigeon Hole Principle(Contrapositive)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us define $N_k = \{0,1 \ldots , k\}$.

If there exists an injection $N_m$ $\rightarrow$ $N_n$, then $m \leq n$.
How do I go about proving this?
It intuitively makes sense, I'm just unsure how to go about proving it?

Comment: With that injection you may assume $N_m\subseteq N_n$.

Comment: @RaziehNoori So I can just state that?
Then say that either $N_m = N_n$ or $N_m \subset N_n$, which by definition of a equal sets and proper subsets proves it?

Comment: use user15382's answer. it works very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m,n$ be finite and $f:N_m\to N_n$ be an injection. Then $f$ is a bijection onto its image $f:N_m\to f(N_m)$. So $f(N_m)\subseteq N_n\implies m=$#$f(N_m)\leq $#$N_n=n$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is an injection $[0 \ldots m] \rightarrow [0 \ldots n]$.
Let us work with induction on $m$. When $m=0$ it is true.

Let $i = f(m)$. Then, when
\begin{align}
g(x) &= x \,{\rm when }\, x \neq i,n\\
g(i) &= n\\ 
g(n) &= i\\ 
\end{align}
you get that $g\circ f$ restricted to $[0\ldots m-1]$ is an injection (composition of an injection and a bijection) to $[0\ldots n-1]$. Using induction, $m-1 \leq n-1$ hence $m\le n$.